Installing Watchman on Fedora using Homebrew - Potential conflicts with DNF
I'm trying to install Watchman on Fedora, but the GitHub releases don't provide .rpm packages. The only option seems to be installing using Homebrew (brew). However, I'm concerned about potential conflicts with DNF, Fedora's package manager.
Can I safely install Watchman using brew on Fedora without compromising my system's package management? Are there any specific precautions or workarounds I should consider?
What I tried:
I checked the Watchman GitHub releases page for Fedora-compatible packages (.rpm).
I researched alternative installation methods, which led me to consider installing Watchman using Homebrew (brew).
What I was expecting:
To find .rpm packages for Watchman on the GitHub releases page, making installation straightforward.
A clear indication of whether installing brew on Fedora would conflict with DNF, Fedora's package manager.
